# I want to add a field to my table but I keep getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I type this into my terminal:

`rails generate migration AddDetailsToOrders name:text`

And get this error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method`text' for main:Object`

Comment: Why don't you just create the migration manually?

Comment: I guess I could.  I'm new to Ruby on Rails so I want to make sure I'm doing it right.  Do I need to make a new migration file or can I add it to an existing one?

Comment: You'd be best adding to a new file - I'll write an answer for you

Comment: This command is perfectly correct, provided you run it on terminal within the application root folder. It looks like you running this command from `rails console` which will give this error?

Comment: @KirtiThorat is right, rails is a command that you run from your system shell (e.g. bash) not from your ruby console.

Comment: Ha!  I am still in the rails console.  Thanks @Kirti Thorat -- Exited the rails console by typing `exit` + Return

Comment: @jiggabits Glad to help. :) I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rails generate migration AddDetailsToOrders name:text
```

The command you are using to generate the migration is absolutely correct. BUT it must be fired on terminal within the rails application root folder. You are getting this error because you are trying to run the `rails generate` command within `rails console`.

Exit the `rails console` and then run the command on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're new, you should do something like this:

```
$ rails generate migration AddDetailsToOrders

#db/migrate/____.rb
class AddDetailstoOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :name, :text
  end
end
```